# парсер на python,выдаёт ошибку 403 forbidden

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

я написал код который парсит всю инфу о юзерах https://unsplash.com/napi/photos?per_page=12&page=1 и так до https://unsplash.com/napi/photos?per_page=12&page=23000 но на больших цифрах например https://unsplash.com/napi/photos?per_page=12&page=16000 выдаёт ошибку 403 forbidden но при смени ip он открывается

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json 
import csv 
import time
from datetime import datetime

for j in range(23000):
    time.sleep(1)
    r = requests.get("https://unsplash.com/napi/photos?per_page=12&page=" + str(j),headers={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36"})
    data = r.json()
    for i in range(len(data)):
        try:
            accepted_tos = data[i]['user']['accepted_tos']
            bio = data[i]['user']['bio']
            bio = str(bio).replace("\r\n", " ")
            first_name = data[i]['user']['first_name']
            id = data[i]['user']['id']
            instagram_username = data[i]['user']['instagram_username']
            last_name = data[i]['user']['last_name']
            location = data[i]['user']['location']
            name = data[i]['user']['name']
            portfolio_url = data[i]['user']['portfolio_url']
            total_collections = data[i]['user']['total_collections']
            total_likes = data[i]['user']['total_likes']
            total_photos = data[i]['user']['total_photos']
            twitter_username = data[i]['user']['twitter_username']
            updated_at = data[i]['user']['updated_at']
            username = str(data[i]['user']['username'])        
            all_info = open('info.csv', mode='a+',encoding="utf-8") 
            info_writer = csv.writer(all_info, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            item = {"accepted_tos":str(accepted_tos),
                    "bio":str(bio),
                    "first_name":str(first_name),
                    "id":str(id), 
                    "instagram_username":str(instagram_username), 
                    "last_name":str(last_name),
                    "location": str(location), 
                    "name":str(name),
                    "portfolio_url":str(portfolio_url),
                    "total_collections": str(total_collections), 
                    "total_likes":str(total_likes),
                    "total_photos":str(total_photos), 
                    "twitter_username":str(twitter_username), 
                    "updated_at":str(updated_at), 
                    "username":str(username)
                }
            info_writer.writerow([item['accepted_tos'],item['bio'],item["first_name"],item["id"],item['instagram_username'],item['last_name'],item['location'],item['name'],item['portfolio_url'],item["total_collections"],item['total_likes'],item['total_photos'],item['twitter_username'],item['updated_at'],item['username']])
            all_info.close()    
        except:
            print(j)
            continue
```

Comment: Думаю, там стоит защита от парсинга, поэтому все нормально-нормально, а потом сервер понимает, что уж очень много обращений с одного ip и банит. Тут вариант или поменять IP после 403 forbidden и/или делать time.sleep(1) между обращениями

Comment: В просто досили сайт, поэтому вас заблокировали. Нужно добавлять задержки между запросами

Comment: с задержкой тоже самое

Comment: @Xch0, задержка в 1 секунду это не панацея, вас могли, например, за количество обращений в час заблокировать

Comment: @Xch0, когда я делал парсеры, где куча запросов, то добавлял повторы неуспешного запроса (https://github.com/gil9red/Check_with_notification/blob/2a878d752efa9a0e83b49bab5e2bd83d9ffd0e77/root_common.py#L97), плюс задержки между запросами могли быть были рандомные (типа, от 1 до 2.5 секунд), плюс при проблемах с сайтом делал большие задержки (от 5 минут) с инкрементальной задержкой (типа 5 минут, 10 минут, 15, ...): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/html_parsing/get_game_genres/main.py#L77

Comment: всё что вы сейчас в мне говорите я пробовал